# Sub selecting (checking) checkboxes that have a specified tag in Jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a tricky jquery question; I want to be able to select all the childs of a specific checkbox when it has a span class identer and content '-- '

In the example below; I want that when I check 'Alarme' both 'Alarmes domestiques' and 'Contrôle d'accès' to be checked; also the reverse action when I unselect it.

Must be damn easy but i'm not a Jquery expert.

Thanks !

[image: Layout]

I have the following code :

```
<tbody>
 <tr class="odd">
     <td>
     <div class="form-item-2-0-checkboxes-1--1">
         <input type="checkbox" name="2[0][checkboxes][1][-1]" value="1">
     </div>
     </td>
     <td>
          <span class="indenter"></span>
          <a href="/taxonomy/term/1" class="depth-0">Alarmes</a>
     </td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="even">
     <td>
         <div class="form-item-2-0-checkboxes-4--1">
              <input type="checkbox" name="2[0][checkboxes][4][-1]" value="1">
         </div>
     </td>
     <td>
          <span class="indenter">--&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="/taxonomy/term/4" class="depth-1">Alarmes domestiques</a>
     </td> 
 </tr>
 <tr class="odd">
     <td>
          <div class="form-item-2-0-checkboxes-5--1">
              <input type="checkbox" name="2[0][checkboxes][5][-1]" value="1">
          </div>
     </td>
     <td>
          <span class="indenter"></span>
          <a href="/taxonomy/term/2" class="depth-0">Aménagement</a>
     </td> 
 </tr>
 <tr class="even">
      <td>
          <div class="form-item-2-0-checkboxes-3--1">
              <input type="checkbox" name="2[0][checkboxes][3][-1]" value="1">
          </div>
      </td>
      <td>
          <span class="indenter"></span>
          <a href="/taxonomy/term/3" class="depth-0">Sanitaires</a>
      </td> 
 </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, try that, not really nice code yet.

```
$checkboxes = $("span.indenter:empty").parent().prev().children().children();
$checkboxes.click(function(){
    var $t = $(this);
    var checked = $t.is(':checked');
    var $tr = $t.parent().parent().parent();
    var child;

    do {    $tr = $tr.next();
            if(!$tr.length) return;
            child = ! $tr.children(":nth-child(2)").children("span").is(":empty");
            if( child )
                $tr.children(":nth-child(1)").children().children().prop('checked',checked);
    } while(child);
});
```

Comment: Nice but doesn't even trigger the click; 
(function($) { $checkboxes =              $("span.indenter:empty").parent().prev().children().children();
 $checkboxes.click(function() { alert ('hey'); });})(jQuery);

Comment: it must work http://jsfiddle.net/YSSps/ but cannot test fiddle with the 1.5.2 (and take care about .prop who was added in jquery 1.6)

Comment: Perfect; I missed a 'ready' function; updated the code http://jsfiddle.net/YSSps/1/ many thanks; i'll ask another question will keep you posted if you're interested.

Comment: Many thanks; works like a charm. Here's another challenge for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851614/unselect-parent-checkbox-when-all-childrens-are-unselected-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to trigger an event once you check the Alarmes box to check the other two. Put the two sub-items into the same class (for this example, we'll say "subChk" is the class)

```
    $("#Alarmes").click(function() {
        $(".subChk").prop('checked', $("#Alarmes").is(':checked')); 
    });
```

Thanks for correction.

Comment: or smaller : $(".subChk").prop('checked', $("#Alarmes").is(':checked') );

Comment: Thanks but the code i provided was only an example; can you provide a more generic solution ? I'll have around 60 checkboxes down there; but using the exact same logic. Also, the solution you provided will not work as there's no '.subChk' class defined.

Comment: You can define the class within the <input> tags. <input type="checkbox" class="subChk">

Comment: again; i cannot modify the code; i can only add javascript to this dynamically generated code.

Comment: does all sub checkbox parent tr get the "even" class ?

Comment: nope; but they all get the '<span class="indenter">--&nbsp;</span>' code and others simply '<span class="indenter"></span>' see the image.